# KTOR-JWT-Auth to Support PS256

Tags: kotlin, jwt, ktor, nimbus-jose-jwt

I have a ktor application that uses graphQL internally and serves different frontend applications. Now all these application have their own way of obtaining jwt tokens where I handle verification and validation. Everything is fine until this point using ktor-jwt-auth but problem comes when I try verifying a PS256 based token as that's not supported by ktor-jwt-auth. Anyone facing the similar issue or any idea with the way forward regarding this?

I need to retain the existing authentication mechanism as well and also add the support for PS256. I am thinking of using nimbusJose but I don't think I can use that alongwith ktor-jwt-auth out of the box.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.